# How to debug MissingPropertyExceptionMessage error in Grails?

Tags: grails

User.grrovy

```
package com

class User {
    String name

    static constraints = {
        name blank:false

    }
}
```

Usercontroller.groovy

```
package com

class UserController {

    def index() {
        redirect(action:sup)
    }
    def sup(){
        def person=[name:'sai']
        def user=new User(person)
        assert s.name=='sai'

    }
}
```

When I am running this task it shows:

> Error 500: Internal Server Error
>
> URI:/practice/user/indexClass:groovy.lang.MissingPropertyExceptionMessage:No such property: sup for class: com.moog.UserController

Comment: Your question does not meeting SO guidelines. Please take moment  to finish the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). Improve the question title and content.

Answer (score 1):

you should have:

```
redirect(action:'sup')
```

Comment: thank you for your reply jayan but its not working it shows Error 404/practice/WEB-INF/grails-app/views/user/sup.jsp

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

type Status report

message /practice/WEB-INF/grails-app/views/user/sup.jsp

description The requested resource is not available.

Comment: how about you add render text: 'we did something' you are not rendering anything and don't appear to have a gsp created by the name of sup under folder of user in views

Comment: Q.  iam installing grails 3.4 version and java 1.8 when iam running grails application it shows java.lang.exceptions error how to fix it plz help me

Comment: this is my new question i want add template.gsp to another view file how? iam using like<g:render template="template" /> but it shows template name and path not found .help me?

Comment: Hi i want to know how to add templates to corresponding view files

Comment: from docs: "Grails uses the convention of placing an underscore before the name of a view to identify it as a template."
So if you have a template: _test.gsp in same dir as gsp view you should do: <g:render template="test"/>. If in different dir you should set full path, for example <g:render template="/differentDir/test"/>